# Integrating JavaScript libraries (Potree) in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, libraries

I am trying to integrate the WebGL based point cloud renderer [Potree](http://potree.org/) into my Laravel project. I am fairly new to web app development and have been struggling with the correct way to add JavaScript libraries to a Laravel project.

I have been using Potree with XAMPP successfully by copying the generated Potree folder into XAMPP/htdocs. The folder contains:

- Index.html
- pointclouds (folder): contains point cloud data
- libs (folder): collection of libraries to render point cloud such as Potree, Three.js, jquery, jstree etc...

I am now trying to use this in Laravel but I am unsure of the correct way to store the libs folder. I moved the Potree folder into ./Resources and Index.html into ./Resources/Views:

This is currently how Index.html is trying to access the libraries:

[image: Index.html]

However each stylesheet and script fails to load with the error: "*net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)*"

I am wondering what the correct way to store/integrate the Potree libraries in Laravel is and how to reference them. I have been looking at using Laravel mix but I don't think it is necessary here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Either use webpack to move the files from the `resources` folder to the `public` folder or place your `libs` and `pointclouds` folders in the `public` folder. Files in the `resources` folder are not publicly available

Comment: Thanks, this solved it straight away!